# Date <> Currentdate

Tags: cognos, report-studio

I am trying to apply a date filter form the query in report studio. Unfortunately, there is very limited documentation / pool of examples for Cognos and i'm stuck on what should be a simple problem.

How do I filter out records when `xDate` is not today? The below throws errors

```
[xDate] <> CURRENT_DATE()
```

---

Replacing the operator `<>` with `<` or `!=`  also do not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current_date does not have brackets,  that is why your second iteration worked.  You can also use localtime and localtimestamp.

Comment: Do you know of any good resources for Cognos? I am spoiled now and used to Stack Overflow level of detail and documentation. This does not seem to exist for Cognos. I may just start asking every question possible here to start a respiratory of questions and answers lol

Comment: I usually use google, or https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/search/cognos?type=technotes.  This forum is also useful.

Comment: Forgot about the youtube series  https://community.ibm.com/community/user/businessanalytics/communities/community-home/librarydocuments?communitykey=6b10df83-0b3c-4f92-8b1f-1fd80d0e7e58&tab=librarydocuments

Comment: Thanks! I'm just now having to learn the tool and have not had the best luck in tracking down resources. Plz join in me and adding to the tag `report-studio` that I just created. This is the first tagged question for it. Trend setting starts: `Now()`

Comment: The documentation in the application can help in some ways

There some some Web pages 

https://developer.ibm.com/dwblog/2017/cognos-analytics-resource-guide/   (probably not maintained)

https://www.ibm.com/community/businessanalytics/cognos/
(active)

There used to be a document called proven practices but I can't find it.  It isn't obsolete.

A good grounding with Kimball can help.

Comment: IBM offers some courses too.

https://www.ibm.com/services/learning/ites.wss/zz-en?searchString=cognos%20analytics&pageType=search&noOfResultsPerPage=20&rowStart=0&cc=ca#(cc%3Aca%2Cfilters%3A(trainingType%3ACourse)%2CnumberOfResults%3A'20'%2CpageNumber%3A1%2CpubEntIdentifier%3A''%2Cquery%3A'cognos%20analytics'%2Csorting%3Arelevance%2F%2Fasc%2Ctype%3ACourse%2CviewMode%3A0)

https://www.ibm.com/services/learning/ites.wss/zz-en?pageType=course_description&cc=&courseCode=K01015G

https://www.ibm.com/services/learning/ites.wss/zz-en?pageType=course_description&cc=&courseCode=B6025G